Data is stored in Gregorian date in database but rider shows date in Persian Calendar when I fetch it from database
I have come across a peculiar issue with Rider. Although all dates are stored in the Gregorian calendar format in the database, when I fetch the data from the database, it displays in the Persian calendar, as depicted in the picture below. What could be the cause of this problem? This project is running fine on my colleague's PC, which is running Windows Visual Studio 2022, whereas my system is a Mac. Additionally, I have already tried uninstalling and reinstalling Rider, as well as updating my .NET Core runtime to version 8.0.2.
my system date format is gregorian
as you can see the value of lastItemDb is in persian calender.


If you want a specific format you can do: ....FirstOrDefault().ToString("dd/MM/yy"); otherwise the culture if the machine will be used.

You seem to call To call ToString on a DateTime. You get something according to the local  culture settings then. Your code seems totally culture ignorant before you do anything you might want to read about culture dependent things and how to deal with that (decimal separators, calenders, date formats etc.). And then decide how to fix your code.

@Magnus it gives syntax error: method ToString() has 0 parameter but is invoked with 1

@Ralf It's not a dateTime but a DateOnly object, how can I change this local culture settings you talking about in my code?

Are you sure it is DateOnly? Since DateOnly does have that overload on ToString: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dateonly.tostring?view=net-8.0#system-dateonly-tostring(system-string)
